# Need to access content after facebook authorization javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm new in .js and struggling with content access(angular1 + ionic). For e.g., I used a simple facebook authentication

```
      function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'Appid(can't show it)',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,
    status     : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
  });
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
 });
  };
```

and what I want is that after authenticate(after logging) it would directly  navigate to main content(to view) or even if I'm logged in It would let me use main content. The problem is that I'm new and I don't have enough experience, but what I think I need to use permissions with tokens? Also, I'm doing this locally, so I need use localstorage? It would be very nice to hear other idea.

Comment: so what exactly does not work? did you debug the code? take a look at this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: This is working, the problem is that I don't know how to make for e.g. If there is home.html , main.html would be accessible after authorization with facebook. It's a bit too difficult to understand it as newbie.

Comment: on another page, you have to init the fb sdk again and use FB.getLoginStatus. either way, why are you starting with angularjs? as a newbie, this is way too hard. better start with vanilla js, or react. react is a lot easier.